# Using PHP connecting mysql and Knockout

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, rest, knockout.js

I am trying to connect MySQL database using PHP as a REST API and Knockout JS to display the database in the UI. I am able to make a connection from database to PHP and query the data. As am new to knockout, I am not sure on how to display the data properly using Knockout. Please find my code below. Thanks for your help in advance.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "employeedb";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `currentAddress`, `permanentAddress` FROM `employeedata` WHERE 1";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $records = array();

  while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $records[] = array(
          'id' => $row['id'], 'firstname' => $row['firstname'], 'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 'currentAddress' => $row['currentAddress'], 'permanentAddress' => $row['permanentAddress']
      );
  }

  echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

JS Code:

```
var dataModel = function  () {
    var self = this;

    this.employeeRecord = ko.observableArray([]);
    // Display Records
    this.displayRecord = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            datatype: "json",
            url: "js/phpapi.php",
            success: function (data) {
                var id = data['id'];
                var firstname = data['firstname'];
                var lastname = data['lastname'];
                var currentAddress = data['currentAddress'];
                var permanentAddress = data['permanentAddress'];
                self.employeeRecord.push(data);
            }
        });
    };
    this.displayRecord();
    console.log (self.employeeRecord());
};
ko.applyBindings(new dataModel());
```

I am able to 'GET' the 'URL' correct but the entire data is displayed in array [0]. Let me know if I am missing something.

Output: when console.log (data)

```
"[{"id":"1","firstname":"Test Data","lastname":"number 1","currentAddress":"Temporary Current Address 1","permanentAddress":"Permanent Address 1"},
  {"id":"2","firstname":"Test Data","lastname":"number 2","currentAddress":"Temporary Current Address 2","permanentAddress":"Permanent Address 2"}]"
```

Comment: Add "console.log(data)" to your success function and tell us what it looks like. I'm guessing that your api is returning an object instead of an array.

Comment: @JasonSpake - I've added the Output when I did "console.log (data)".

Comment: Hmm. Try changing "self.employeeRecord.push(data);" to "self.employeeRecord.push(JSON.parse(data));"

Comment: That's Great! It worked. Thank you so much @JasonSpake